# R - How to get the value of a variable to be treated as a constant?

Tags: r

In R, how can I use the value of a variable as a constant when defining a function?

In a loop, I want to do something like:

```
theta <- vector[n]

f <- function(x)
{
    v <- theta * x
    return(v)
}
```

But I need to be able to redefine theta later and not have this change the definition of the function? I've looked into get() but this runs into the same problem.

Comment: Generally, functions should not depend on constants in your global environment. In this case, `f` should be a function of both `theta` and `x`. It would be a very strange case to define a function *inside* the loop. Define the function outside the loop and then inside the loop use `f(x, theta[i])`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
f <- function(theta) {
    t <- theta
    function(x) t * x
}
theta <- 5
g <- f(theta)
# g is now a function that multiplies its argument by 5
g(2)
#[1] 10
# Now try to modify theta in the global environment
theta <- 6
# g doesn't change
g(2)
#[1] 10
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that this is a simple example of _closure_.

Comment: Thanks! Does this work because the t is local to the function? Is it correct that when executing R just sets up a function g, rather than going through f each time we evaluate g(.)?

Comment: Yes `g` has its own associated environment (which you can see for example if you just type `print(g)`). There is lots of info in Hadley's book http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html